# Filer values out of checkbox

Tags: list, inspect

I was using following code to select all check box and it worked for̥ me, but I like to use filter not to select all values but only few... For example,in given below code, it'll select all the check box. Also, if I like to select only chk1 from the below list .. is there any way , I can do it?

```
(function() {
var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
    aa[i].checked = true;
}ṇ
```

}

chk 1
chk 2
chk 3

Comment: Please the tags corresponding to your language or framework, and add some code.

Comment: (function() {
    var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        aa[i].checked = true;
    }ṇ
 }

Comment: What language is that? JavaScript? If so, please add the tag to your question.